# Does the temperature affect the working of a PCB circuit?

Tags: pcb, dc, dc-dc-converter, temperature, enclosure

I use an MP2305DS to convert 12V 5A to 3.3V 2A.

The PCB is in a standard IP68 box.

Does the temperature affect the operation of the PCB circuit?

Comment: Temperature affects everything, not just electronics. Sometimes a little, sometimes a lot. You need to be more specific about what it is you want to know. Using less words if your English is not good is not helpful. Using many words helps us understand what you want.

Comment: @DKNguyen *fewer words ;-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany True. I only know that vbecause of the Apollo13 movie.

Comment: with your max output power, the converter alone will dissipate at least 800mW as heat. I'd personally attach a heatsink or a large thermal pad for dissipation.

Comment: I do not recommend using that part as it is about to become obsolote, so after you go through all the effort youll need to redesign later if you want to make more. Also, 2A is at this parts' limits, try to get an oversized one that can do 3A so that is can run cooler.

Answer (score 2):

Temperature will affect the circuit. A standard PCB is rated to 120-130C, electrolytic capacitors experience faster wear at higher temperatures, and many semiconductors die at anywhere from 80-150C, with exceptions of course. Your buck converter is rated to 85C, so dont exceed that.

Now the question becomes how do I make sure not to exceed that? Your part claims ~88% effeciency at 3.3V 2A, which is 6.6W. Thus this converter will dissipate 0.8W of power. The air inside the sealed enclosure will heat up. Let's take two extreme scenarios: The box is made of metal and submerged in cold water, or it is thermally isolated. In scenario 1, it will probably not overheat. In scenario 2, it will probably eventually overheat.

The way you get to know this is from the thermal resistance of the enclosure. Check to see if it is provided, then visit references that inform you about thermal resistance calculations

Answer (score 0):

12V 5A is what is available from the source, 60 Watts. You convert to 3.3V 2A That is 6.6 watts, considerably less then what is available. Oversizing will help it to run cooler and last longer. You can use a smaller power source if you like. As stated earlier temperature does effect all of the components. Temper changes also can cause problems as the parts expand and shrink with temperature changes. They are microscopic in movement but movement is movement and stresses the components. The part you mentioned the MP2305DS has a maximum junction temperature of 150C, exceeding that will damage the part. Note that is junction not case temperature. There is thermal resistance between that junction to the case and from the case to its environment. Each of these will have a temperature drop referencing the junction. The data sheet gives you information to calculate this. It's in the watts. You state: "I use pcb in the standard box ip68", that does not tell us anything about its ability to dissipate heat, that is design, size and material dependent..

Comment: In fact, IP68 isn't even a standard type of box--it's a rating for boxes, indicating that it's pretty much as dust- and waterproof as you can get. Which has nothing to do with heat dissipation, except perhaps that it'll have poor ventilation.